# visual basic code error

Tags: vbscript

I have this code:

```
Private sub form_activate()
  For n = 1 to 10
    For i = 20 to 40
      If i-n=14 then
        Exit for
      End if
      Else
        Message = "love"
      End if
End sub
```

But these codes resulting error, please let me know where are the fault?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: More importantly: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Two missing Next and a completely messed up If/Else/End If structure. Start from

```
Private sub form_activate()
  For n = 1 to 10
    For i = 20 to 40
      If i-n=14 then
         Exit for
      End if
      ' Else ' ???
      Message = "love"
      ' End if ' ???
    Next
  Next
End sub
```

and work out the desired middle part.